# jQuery $.ajax post show partial results

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-post

Is possible to get partial results and write to a div from a $.ajax post?

My js code

```
$('#submit').livequery('click', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#loading').show();
    var myvar= $("#myvar").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        cache: false,
        data: ({'myvar':myvar}),
        success: function(data){
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#main_content').html(data);
        },
    });
    return false;  
});
```

The code from process.php

```
function send($string = "") {
echo $string;
echo str_pad('', 4096)."\n";
@ob_flush();
@flush();
}
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
send($i);
sleep(5);
}
```

Is possible to show on #main_content the result like this:

- show 1 -> wait -> show 2 -> wait .....

Right now i get all result after the process is made: 12345678910

Comment: You would have write something to handle the data that was retrieved as PHP will return everything at once.

Comment: if i open the php file in browser i get the result that i want (i am using the ob_flush function)

Comment: Right, that is because PHP is handling the output - once sent to the client via AJAX you'll have to handle client-side unless you want to make multiple AJAX calls.

Comment: i submit the form once with jquery, then the php file will process data. The process can take more than 5 minutes so i want to show once an action is completed. I am new to jquery and i can't see how i can make multiple calls to the same post file since i want to post the data only once ...

Comment: perhaps you should think about changing up the process...what on earth is taking 5 minutes?

Comment: at any rate, you could always use a threaded approach if what you are looking for is some sort of progress indicator.  I hate PHP for it's disgusting syntax so I can't offer an example, but I assume it can't be too hard to implement.  check here http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is run on the server and, as such, cannot affect the client-side browser behavior like you are asking.  The way to accomplish what you want is to pass all the information from PHP to your browser and handle the logic in jQuery or javascript.  Send all of your information and store it in some variables/arrays and after your POST, split up the info and display it to the browser with a timeout callback like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Optionally, you could break it up on the server side and have it make a new call to fetch say..the next 20 results like Google or any other search engine does. This would limit the amount of data that you would need to store client side and prevent your site from becoming slow and bogged down.

Comment: you can do the fetch inside the setTimeout function :P...just depends what he wants to do...but yes I agree that is a good consideration to keep in mind as well..+1'd

Comment: The PHP file will get some data and will start making some actions based when the data taht is receiving, i just want to output a message after an action is completed.